# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).sortable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, reactjs, webpack

I'm new to React and rigthnow having a problem when calling sortable method in my file.jsx :

```
import $ from 'jquery'
...

    $('.myId').sortable( //error when calling sortable//
    {
      .....
    ......
    })
...
```

I already put :

```
"jquery": "^2.2.3",
 "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5",
 "jquery.ui.widget": "^1.10.3",
```

to package.json. So I think my windows environment is oki to for playing with react. The problem is there is an error when calling `$('#myId').sortable()` any idea how to solve this guys? 
Thanks in advance :)

Note : 
I have tried to put :

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

to my file.php that using $('.myId'), but it still doesn't work..

Comment: Reasons may be try loading jquery library files first before sortable js .. also try different versions < 2. Check in network tab in console window whether JS loaded.

Comment: Suggestion: If you are developing your app in React, you really don't need jquery. As React and Jquery have totally different perception how they look at the DOM.

Comment: Hay @AB Udhay, How to load jquery lib first...??? mmm... I think I loaded that first because it's bundled in react...

Comment: Hay @MaheshHaldar, mmm.... I don't really know the perception, so I think I don't have any choice for now without using sortable from jquery :)

Comment: Have u tried different versions of jquery?

Comment: Not yet, I thought newest version is oki.. :)
But okie, lemme try it then Mr. @ABUdhay..

Comment: ooowh... btw Do I have to just change jquery version @ABUdhay..?? what about jquery-ui and jquery.ui.widget...??

Comment: jquery version is enought 1.10 or 1.11 series.. but i'm not sure it may/maynot solve your problem.. need addtional inputs if not

Comment: I just tried jquery 1.11.1... But the error is still there Mr.@AbuUdhay...

Comment: ooowh... btw, if I change iimport $ from 'jquery' to import $ from 'jquery-ui', the error is gone, but there is another error called "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined"

Comment: I think, I shouldn't change jquery to jquery-ui... >.<

Comment: If you are including jquery with a `<script>` tag (instead of a module bundler), then either you need to tell your module bundler it's external, or you have to use `window.jQuery`.

Comment: actually, I'm not using window.jquery...I just try to put <scripty>..</script>, I hoped it worked... butt not luck... :'(

Answer (score 0):

For how to use JQuery in React you can refer to this answer 
[Jquery in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518278/how-to-use-jquery-on-reactjs/41381583)

but you will still face the same error as you are using third party javascript library.

Since its global variable so you need `window.$('#id').sortable`

```
import $ from 'jquery'
...

window.$('.myId').sortable( //error when calling sortable//
{
  .....
......
})
...
```

This will solve your problem and don't forget to use `componentDidMount(){...}`