# datatable in reactjs not working in jQuery

Tags: reactjs, adminlte

It is giving this error on console. So how to resolve this type error?     HTML and CSS coming properly only jQuery is not comming.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined at
>   dataTables.bootstrap.js:47

I am using AdminLTE template. In that datatables not working.

```
$.extend( true, DataTable.defaults, {dom:
    "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
renderer: 'bootstrap'
} );
```

I am using AdminLTE template. In that datatables not working. So how to resolve this type of problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what is your question. It seems your argument `DataTable` has no `defaults` property (or it is `undefined`). Please edit your question to reflect what exactly you were expecting and what went wrong

Comment: Sir but it is there. dataTables.bootstrap.js:47 in this that code is available I am using Reactjs . and I am converting HTML to JSX all code so that error is coming

Answer (score 1):

Make sure jQuery has loaded properly:

[1][How to use JQuery on ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518278/how-to-use-jquery-on-reactjs/47540936#47540936)