# window, document and $ is not defined in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How to use jquery & custom js like : **$("#header").sticky({ topSpacing: 0, zIndex: "50" });** in reactjs

Below config is not working for me.

I am using this repo.
  https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-universally

```
import $ from 'jquery';
require('bootstrap3');
require('../../assets/lib/stickyjs/sticky')
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  global.window = {}
  global.document = {}
}
```

> SERVER: Error in server execution, check the console for more info.
>
> ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JQuery on ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518278/how-to-use-jquery-on-reactjs)

Comment: @AndrewL  Okay but getting below error. how to solve it.
ReferenceError: window is not defined

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
let w = window;
let $ = w.$;
```