# jquery(#myModal).modal('show) is not working

Tags: jquery, reactjs

```
componentDidMount(){
  jQuery(function($) {          
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
}
```

I'm using jquery with reactjs, When i'm using this, an error is getting is like

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function.

I don't know why this error is coming

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Jayakar! It's difficult to say what might be wrong without seeing more code. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you most likely don't want to use jQuery for this. Consider changing a value in your component state and use that to conditionally render the modal instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JQuery on ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518278/how-to-use-jquery-on-reactjs)