# Already rendered page on Server having Jquery event handling not working in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I have integrated the DocuVieware in react which returns html file rendered on server. when I render the html in react first thing is it is not visible so I had to remove the visibility: hidden in css.Now the css and jquery handling files are separately downloaded and loaded in index.html file in link and script tags. now when I click on any button of the rendered html. It call onclick event already defined and implemented in the jquery file I included given by DocuVieware. when some button is clicked it calls the event handler but throws error in console as

> (index):1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'LoadFromFile_Click' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
>   ((index):1)

I have imported jquery 3.1.1 as instructed by DocuViewer. I checked in the js file of docuvieware the events are there already.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="docuviewareStyle.css">
<script src="docuvieware-min.js">
</script>
```

the event.control is undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use JQuery with ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518278/how-to-use-jquery-with-reactjs)

Comment: Its completely different question. Already seen that question.