# How to import CDN dependency into create-react-app set up?

Tags: reactjs, datatables, create-react-app, cdn

I'm trying to utilize create-react-app to create a [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) table, and I want to load the dependencies in via CDN.

I've created this table successfully with simple html/javascript (see below, [codepen here](https://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/vogBQe?editors=1000))

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="display" id="example" style="width:100%"></table>
    <script>
           $("#example").DataTable({
     data: [
       {
         first_name: "Tiger",
         last_name: "Nixon",
         position: "System Architect"
       },
       {
         first_name: "Garrett",
         last_name: "Winters",
         position: "Accountant"
       }
     ],
     columns: [
       { data: "first_name", title: "first" },
       { data: "position", title: "secon" }
     ]
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to produce the same result with create-react-app.

I've tried the following and also replicated within this [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-hodgkin-upjbd)

Added the following dependencies to public/index.html

```
  <link href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
```

Added the three dependencies to the external resources in codesandbox

[image: Added the three dependencies to the external resources]

Below is the component where DataTables is suppose to render

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    $("#example").DataTable({
      data: [
        {
          first_name: "Tiger",
          last_name: "Nixon",
          position: "System Architect"
        },
        {
          first_name: "Garrett",
          last_name: "Winters",
          position: "Accountant"
        }
      ],
      columns: [
        { data: "first_name", title: "first" },
        { data: "position", title: "secon" }
      ]
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table id="example" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You didn't find any other react based component or you must use jquery?

Comment: I must use JQuery since I need JQuery for other things too

Comment: Well, I can only advise not to do that, you should refer to docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518278/how-to-use-jquery-with-reactjs, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In your code sandbox, you’ve imported jQuery again, even though it’s already there thanks to your CDN links. If you remove that import, it appears to work now.

You might have to adjust some eslint rules to tell CRA that you’re using jQuery, but that should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks - I got it to work within CodeSandbox following your instruction to remove that jQuery import. I then exported the CodeSandbox to zip, ran npm install, and then npm start, and I received the following error:  TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7___default(...)(...).DataTable is not a function. I wonder why this code behaves differently when you run it from CodeSandbox versus locally

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I can’’t be too certain about that either. The error itself reads as if your Datatables script isn’t being loaded, or if it is, that it’s not occurring in the correct order. I haven’t played with Create React App in quite a long time, so I’d be grasping at straws to try to help you as-is. Do you have a public repo of this? I could clone that and give it a whirl

Comment: Yep - I just created a public repo for this specific question here: https://github.com/ChrisCruze/create-react-app-cdn