# How to use jQuery in React ^16.8.0(Function Component using Hook)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, html5-canvas

I 'm new in React.
I hope to extract an image to canvas using jQuery in react.
But as you can see in behind, I can't use $.
Could you tell me the reason?
Thank you for your cooperation.

```
function display(extract) {

  const canvas = $('#overlay').get(0)
  api.match(canvas, $('#inputImg').get(0))

  $('#Container').empty()
  Images.forEach(canvas => $('#Container').append(canvas))

}
```

Comment: According to React version ^16.8.0 upgrade, it can't use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you forgot to add the necessary module for the JQuery, or it was added incorrectly.

There is a similar topic on your topic:

[How to use JQuery with ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518278/how-to-use-jquery-with-reactjs)

Hope it will help :)