# React equivilant of `$(window).scrollTop()`

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm trying to check if a user has scrolled to the bottom of a document. There's a popular [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom) answered only in Jquery.

How can the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3898152/10211923) be done in React?

So far, I figured out that the equivalent of:

- `$(window).height` is: `window.pageYOffset`
- `$(document).height` is: `document.documentElement.offsetHeight`

I'm missing `$(window).scrollTop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to check if a user has scrolled to the bottom of a document using React/JS.

Here you go.

[Working demo in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-check-if-page-end-45wi0?file=/src/App.js)

**Code snippet**

```js
export default function App() {
  const [isPageEnd, setIsPageEnd] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", trackScrolling);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("scroll", trackScrolling);
  }, []);

  const trackScrolling = () => {
    if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
      setIsPageEnd(true);
    }
    if (false) {
      console.log(" bottom reached");
      document.removeEventListener("scroll", trackScrolling);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {isPageEnd ? (
        <p> you reached bottom of page. Refresh page and begin again</p>
      ) : (
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in
          laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to
          an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have
          scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a
          type specimen book Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is
          dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The
          passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who
          is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et
          Malorum for use in a type specimen book Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it
          is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or
          web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the
          15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De
          Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book Lorem
          ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in
          laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to
          an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have
          scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a
          type specimen book Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is
          dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The
          passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who
          is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et
          Malorum for use in a type specimen book
        </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new API in the window object. Example here is for scroll to top. You can make it for the bottom also. instead of top give as bottom

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Top:

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Bottom:

```
window.scrollTo({ top: document.body.scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth' })
```

Check the bottom of the page in javascript

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  var d = document.documentElement;
  var offset = d.scrollTop + window.innerHeight;
  var height = d.offsetHeight;

  console.log('offset = ' + offset);
  console.log('height = ' + height);

  if (offset >= height) {
    console.log('At the bottom');
  }
};
```

use with the combination of react hooks

Follow these articles and code references:
1. https://gist.github.com/romanonthego/223d2efe17b72098326c82718f283adb
2. https://medium.com/better-programming/create-a-scroll-to-top-arrow-using-react-hooks-18586890fedc

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting too much from React. React is only concerned with rendering data to the DOM. [You can still use jQuery with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518278/how-to-use-jquery-with-reactjs) is you don't like using pure JS.

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    
    $(window).scrollTop($(document).height());
    
  }, [])

  return <div style={{height: '200vh', background: 'blue'}}></div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I prefer to do it using the browser's API if it's easy. Jquery in this case, is an unnecessary dependency imo. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This probably will work for you. You can use React SyntheticEvent for this purpose

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
   findBottomScroll = e => {
     let element = e.target
     if (element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight) {
       // whatever you want
   }
}
render() {
  return (
    <div onScroll={this.handleScroll}></div>
  )
}
```

}