# How can I use <script> tags inside a JSX file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I just converted some HTML to JSX but inside the HTML file were several script tags. Here is the code below:

```
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/truffle-contract.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am wondering how to use them in the JSX file, which I've turned into a component. Do I import them?

Comment: I'd suggest adding these to the index.html file since they are static.

Comment: You are better off converting to using React Bootstrap and get rid of bootstrap.js and jQuery completely. It's just not as simple as adding the same files in a react app

Answer (score 1):

You should add the scripts in index.html like I show you below. Also, you should avoid to use jquery with React check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518278/how-to-use-jquery-with-reactjs).

```
+-- React root dir
    +-- public
        +-- index.html
```

index.html

```
<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
    --> add scripts here
</body>
```

Also, you can import Bootstrap read [this](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction).