# Beginner - Callback function after dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I've just started learning react so I was wondering if there's a way to do this or even if it's the correct way of doing it.

I have in my App.js a component called DeckTable

```
return (
    <>
      <DeckTable decksCompared={decksCompared} sideboardsCompared={sideboardsCompared} decks={decks} headerCompared={headerCompared} />
    </>
)
```

In the DeckTable.js I'll use those values passed from the App.js and create a table concatenating strings and return it using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, like so:

```
var html = '<table>...</table>'
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
```

Is this the best/correct way of doing it? If I need to call a function now after the table is rendered on the screen where/how would I do that?

If you guys need any more info, just ask.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Why would you generate the HTML yourself? Why not *actually* use React to make the table for you? React allows you to use stuff like `Array.map` to render table rows. There's (almost) never a good reason to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` - hence the name of the attribute saying *dangerous*.

Comment: I've tried doing that but couldn't make it work. Could you give me an example how would I receive the data, process it and return it, because on the examples I saw the data is immediately used and not processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want DeckTable to return a table with the props you passed on App.js (decksCompared, sideboardsCompared, decks, and headerCompared) you can just return a div with a table that uses those props inside. You shouldn't need to use innerHTML.

Comment: But "decksCompared" is an array that I have to use a "for" to mount the table, I can't just use the values directly into a table because I don't know how many elements it will have

Comment: You can use .map on decksCompared to iterate for every element on the array without knowing the size

Comment: Yeah! I finally figured it out how to do it. It's so much easier this way. 
Just another question, if it's no bother. How do I call a function after que DeckTable is rendered, like a jQuery component to allow drag and drop on the table rows that needs to have the table completely rendered on the screen?

Comment: If you want a drag and drop table you may consider using a drag and drop library like react-dnd or react-beautiful-dnd

Comment: Yeah, I'm using "sortable" library. My doubt is, where should I call a function that affects the table created in the DeckTable component to ensure that this table already exists on the page and has values on it? For example, if I need to do something like `$('table').sortable({...});` where should I declare this code? In the app.js? index.js? decktable.js before the return? This code should be inside another function? Thanks.

Comment: You can use jQuery with react as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518278/how-to-use-jquery-with-reactjs), but I would not recommend it. It would be better if you used a React library to achieve this.

Comment: hmmm...I see...so I will try and do it using a react library. Thank you so much for your help. Will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

It easy to use and understand for beginner

```html
function setDangerousHtml(html, el) {
        if (el === null) return;
        const range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.deleteContents();
        el.appendChild(range.createContextualFragment(html));
}

// Your function for any HTML in react


// Usage Very Simple

<div type='link' ref={setDangerousHtml.bind(null,'<YOUR HTML CODE>')}>
</div>
```