# I try to convert this jquery code into the react js format but i don't have any idea how i achieve this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can I use **jquery** in **react js**

```
<script>
    $('#demo').daterangepicker({
        "startDate": "01/21/2023",
        "endDate": "01/27/2023"
    }, function(start, end, label) {
      console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project folder via terminal and run these commands

```
npm install jquery --save
npm i --save-dev @types/jquery
```

Use `import $ from jquery` into your **JSX** file where you need to use.
your **main.jsx** file will be like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';


//   react code here


$('#demo').daterangepicker({
    "startDate": "01/21/2023",
    "endDate": "01/27/2023"
}, function(start, end, label) {
  console.log('New date range selected: ' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' (predefined range: ' + label + ')');
});

// react code here
```

and your **index.html** will be like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="main.jsx"></script>
</head>
<body>
    //your code
</body>
</html>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518278/how-to-use-jquery-with-reactjs#answer-41381583)